# how to pass values from an array into a prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

so im trying to pass the value price from this array

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(
    [{
      name: "14K bracelet",
      id: "1",
      description: "Beautfull 14K gold Bracelet",
      price: 100.00,
      img: braceletImg,
    }]
  )
```

into here

```
<h1 className="price">{products.price}</h1>{/*this is a prop*/}
```

I call the prop here in cart

```
function Cart({ products })
```

full code of the cart component

```
function Cart({ products }) {
  return(
    <div className="Body">
            {/* {products.map(pr => <h1 className="price">{pr.price}</h1>)} */}
        <div className="Cart-wrapper" >
        <div className="cart-header">
            <h5 className="Product-name cart-text">Product</h5>
            <h5 className="quantity-name cart-text">Quantity</h5>
            <h5 className="price-name cart-text">Price</h5>
            <Button className="btn btn-plus">+</Button>
            <Button className="btn btn-minus">-</Button>
            <div className="card-cart">
                <img className="braceletimg" src={braceletImg} />
                <h1 className="card-body-title">Bracelet title</h1>
                <h1 className="card-body-title seemore"><Link className="Link" to="/Bracelets">Learn More</Link></h1>
                <hr className="cart-hr"></hr>
            </div>
            <div className="div-price">
            {products.map(pr => <h1 key={pr.id} className="price">{pr.price}</h1>)}
            <small className="shippingprice">$5.00 + shipping</small>            
            </div>
                <Button className="btn btn-cart  btn-primary"><Link className="Link" to="/Cart/shipping-buynow">Review Cart</Link></Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cart;
```

hopefully, this gives you a better context of the component

Comment: Please post the full code from your component.

Answer (score 0):

Because `products` is an **array**, you either need to use indexing, or you can process them all using `.map()`.

Using indexing:

```
<h1 className="price">{products[0].price}</h1>
```

Using `.map()`:

```
{products.map(pr => <h1 key={pr.id} className="price">{pr.price}</h1>)}
```

The addition of `key={...}` is needed so React can optimize the rendering. If you don't add it then React will show warnings in the console output. If the items already have a unique id or key value, then it's best to use that.

***Update:***

Your `Cart` component may be getting activated already before **`products`** has been initialized, this would explain the `undefined` errors.

This is quite normal, and to prevent it from being a problem you can check if `products` is empty:

```
function Cart({ products }) {
  if (!products)
      return "Loading...";

  return (
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: this error came up when i tried doing the indexing ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show exactly how you call the `Cart` component. Perhaps you are passing the props incorrectly.

Comment: now it is saying ```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')``` @pilchard

Comment: @evan_tech1234 you'll need to update your question as noted by PeterB. Show the line where you are passing `products`.

Comment: It should be called like this: `<Cart products={products} />`

Comment: i put <Cart products={products} /> into my component and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: See my update for a possible fix

Comment: yup it says loading so i will have to try to make products not say undefined or something like that?

Comment: Yes, probably something is wrong with either the initialization or the passing of the value of `products`. If you can't get that to work then it's probably best to ask a new question, so this question stays on topic.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help